# Recursive query - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, recursive-query, self-join

I have this data and expected result:

```
    Data                Expected Result 
No  A   B                  A    B
1   10  500               10    500                          
2   10  c=20              20    400
3   20  400               30    600
4   30  600               30    700
5   30  c=40              30    800
6   30  c=50              40    700
7   40  700               50    900
8   50  c=60              60    900
9   60  c=70              70    900
10  70  900               10    400
```

I need to perform a self join and get the result.

- For line number 1 the expected result is same as the row.
- For line number 2, I need to take the substring of column B (c=20) as 20 and join with column B and get the result as 400.
- Lines number 5 and 6 need to substring column B and get the result from column A.

I tried a recursive query, but still am not getting the expected result.

```
with rec(A, B, nested) as
(
select A, B, case when instr(B, 'C=') != 0 then substr(B, instr(B, 'C=')) as nested
from table
union all
select A, rec.B from table
inner join rec
on (table.A = rec.nested)
)
select A, B, nested from rec;
```

Comment: You have edited the question and changed the expected results; please [edit] the question again and explain how you get to those results as it is unclear how you get an expected answer of `300 | 800` when 800 does not appear in the input.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Answer for the [initial version of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74026372/2)

You do not need a recursive query. To get your desired output you just need to exclude the rows where `B` starts with `c=`:

```sql
SELECT a, b
FROM   table_name
WHERE b NOT LIKE 'c=%';
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (no, a, b) AS
  SELECT 1, 10, '500'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 10, 'c=20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 20, '400'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 30, '600'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 30, 'c=40' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 30, 'c=50' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 40, '700'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 50, '800'  FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs your desired output:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 500 |
| 20 | 400 |
| 30 | 600 |
| 40 | 700 |
| 50 | 800 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hSRafPDZ)

#### Answer for the [3rd edit of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74026372/3)

You can use a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT a AS a,
       b
FROM   table_name
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
CONNECT BY
       PRIOR b LIKE 'c=%'
AND    PRIOR SUBSTR(b, 3) = a
ORDER BY a, b;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (no, a, b) AS
  SELECT  1, 10, '500'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  2, 10, 'c=20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  3, 20, '400'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  4, 30, '600'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  5, 30, 'c=40' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  6, 30, 'c=50' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  7, 40, '700'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  8, 50, 'c=60' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  9, 60, 'c=70' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 70, '900'  FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 400 |
| 10 | 500 |
| 20 | 400 |
| 30 | 600 |
| 30 | 700 |
| 30 | 900 |
| 40 | 700 |
| 50 | 900 |
| 60 | 900 |
| 70 | 900 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VwvdkAzj)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but i have to check if the value in Column A is available or no and then recursively get the data

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. But it is failing with, ```ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data```

Comment: @JimMacaulay The query runs for your sample data without that error in the fiddle linked in the answer. If your sample data is not representative of your actual data then you should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74026372/edit) to ensure that the sample data is representative of your actual data; otherwise, how do you expect other people to accurately answer your question?

Comment: @JimMacaulay If there is a loop in your data then add a `NOCYCLE` clause to the hierarchical query.